# Explicit conversion from data type date to bigint is not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigint, sqldatetime, sql-convert

This used to work with a column type of `DATEIME` but now it won't with `DATE`.

```
CONVERT(BIGINT,ev.StartDate) * -1
```

Is there anyway to get a `BIGINT` value from a `DATE` column?

Comment: why not just use `select datediff(day,'1900/01/01',ev.StartDate)` and avoid it all together....

Comment: If you are converting dates to integers, you are going for DAY whether you know it or not ;)

Comment: `SELECT CAST(CAST('2017-05-30 00:00:00.000' as datetime) AS decimal(8,2))` will return `42883` and `SELECT CAST(CAST('2017-05-30 12:00:00.000' AS datetime) as decimal(8,2))` will return `42883.50` so each day is represented as a single number, starting at the year 1900.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option.  This will even flip the sign for you

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (StartDate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values ('2017-05-30')

Select DateDiff(DAY,StartDate,-1)
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
-42884
```

Answer (score 5):

You can `cast` the startdate as `datetime` for conversion.

```
CONVERT(BIGINT,CAST(ev.StartDate as DATETIME)) * -1
```

Comment: what's the datatype of `startDate`?

Answer (score 2):

First, dates in SQL Server are counted by days from the year 1900.  A big int starts to be useful at about 2.1 billion.  That corresponds to a year in the range of 5.8 million.  Do you really have dates that large?

Of course, casting to an `int` is not permitted.  You can cast `datetime` values . . . but are there other ways?

One simple way is:

```
select 1 + datediff(day, 0, datecol)
```

The "+ 1" is needed so the value matches the actual conversion.  (You can use "-1" instead of "0" instead.)

Or, perhaps you want Unix time in seconds or milliseconds.  For that:

```
select datediff_big(ms, '1970-01-01', datecol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might require to convert to varchar and then bigint

```
select Convert(bigint,convert(varchar(10),ev.StartDate,112))*(-1)
```